# The file “ColorAttributeTransformer.swift” could not be unlocked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Whenever I try to edit any of my files in any project on XCode I get this error:

**The file “ColorAttributeTransformer.swift” could not be unlocked. Unlocking failed for an unknown reason.**

I have tried unlocking it manually through "get info" in the file manager. But all the files are already in a read and write format. So, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

[here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTPaf.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to edit a file from a cocoapod?

Comment: @aheze I haven't installed a cocoapod. I am using a cocoa touch class though

Comment: Hmm maybe attach a screenshot

Comment: @aheze I've edited the post and added a screenshot

Comment: @Jordan Even the NSManagedObject classes in the screenshot you shared are missing. Is it even compiling?

Comment: @aheze I believe so, I'm still new to programming so I'm not sure what that means lol. It's doing the same thing in my storyboard file as well.